# if ( "compare string " and "compare int ")

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement

compared two strings inside the if statement and used " and " operator then compared two integers.

```
 if( issue == bk[i].name and bk[i].quan !=0 ):
            print " book is available"
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DCC PCMC\Desktop\CSE\python projects\DSA project\lib_class.py", line 141, in                                      <module>
    if( issue == bk[i].name and bk[i].quan !=0 ):
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: `bk[i]` is `int` your sequence `b`. I guess It should be some book object in your list `b` you have overwritten in your code before `if` statement: Add more code here. **or** your assignment is wrong.  I think `bk[i].name` should be assigned in `bk[i].quan`

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example of the structure of the bk list?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear.

It is telling you you have an int with no attribute `name`.

Where do you use `name`?  You use it here:

```
bk[i].name
```

So it must be the case that the value of `bk[i]` is an int.  You probably expected it to be something else.